# Volume gone on 19.04?

Tags: sound, 19.04

The sound icon in the top right corner has gone. If you click there the slider is still there but has no volume icon and does nothing. I typed in alsamixer and it opened a terminal volume mixer and that could change the volume but not the normal one. I am on a Dell Inspiron 7577 on Ubuntu 19.04. How do  I fix this? In settings my laptop speakers and ones through the headphone jack arent detected.